# Is there a limit to the number of function inside a XSockets Controller

Tags: c#, xsockets.net

I have a working controller (plugin) with lots of methods inside, however adding an additional method prevents the worker role from plugin-in  the controller.

I'm running XSockets 4.0 on an Azure Worker Role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the server without a license you can only add 1 custom controller, and not add more than 10 methods.

Thanks Uffe

Answer (score 0):

What kind of license are you using?
What do you mean by a lot of methods? Please specify the number of public properties (both getters and setters) as well as the number of public methods.

My guess would be that you have an invalid license, but the log would tell you that.